# Comments getting executed as command

Tags: unity, c#, 3d-meshes, perlin-noise

I have a script to edit my world on run time and a script to generate a world. When i tried to place a block, something wrong happened, so I tried to make my script into command until I find which line was wrong. However, my comments still seem to execute. I made all the lines of update into comments, I still detect my mouse click, and it is the only script to use mouse click.
Infos:
-using IEnumerator to generate world.
-using /*...*/ for comments
-if I try to put a Debug.Log("..."); in the comment part, it doesnt show up in the console, which is even weirder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this usually happen due to 2 reasons:

1. You have not saved the script. so try to save using **Ctrl+Shift+S** this will save all of the edits happen in all of the scripts.
2. This might have happen due to your IDE is not synced with unity so close your IDE and unity and then restart unity and double click on the script to open it up in IDE. Now do some change in the script and save, then move back to unity check if the loading ring is rotating at lower right end if it does rotating this means unity is compiling the script so wait for it and then Play.

I hope this will help...

Comment: Gosh I feel so dumb. I was saving the script but not the good "copy" of it.

Comment: Yap it happens...